# Move abstract in different language to the left

Tags: horizontal-alignment, abstract

I'm writing a thesis in french and my abstract title "Résumé" has to be on the left side. I managed to do this by adding `\renewcommand*{\abstractname}{\flushleft{Résumé}\hfill}`

My problem is that I can't do the same to the other language abstract " Abstract" which has to move also to the left.

This is how I wrote my second language abstract :

```
\begin{otherlanguage}{english} 
\begin{abstract}
....
\end{abstract}
\end{otherlanguage}
```

Could you help me move my second abstract title to the left ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a small, yet complete code that has the problem?

Comment: \renewenvironment{abstract}[1][]
 {%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
    \otherlanguagetrue
    \begin{otherlanguage}{#1}%
  \fi
  \begin{quotation}
  {\bfseries\centering\abstractname\par}
  \vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip}
  \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{}\\[\dimexpr-\baselineskip]

  
  \medskip
 }
 {%
 
  \par
  \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{}\\[\dimexpr-\baselineskip]
 
  \end{quotation}%
  \ifotherlanguage
    \end{otherlanguage}
  \fi
 }

Comment: It is not a compilable code. We also need the document  class and the relevant packages you load and some minimal text.